# Why does't this draw an orbit and just draws an ellipse?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I started to create a very rough simulation of a solar system using **p5.js**, inspired by **Daniel Shiffman**'s video.

I tried to draw the orbit for every planet by saving the positions where the planet was in an array, then using a for loop to iterate through them and draw a circle at every saved position.

Except it doesn't work!

It should have worked because to be sure that it was the best way to do that I searched and got in another of **Daniel Shiffman**'s videos, and apparently it worked for him but unfortunately not for me!

Could someone please tell me what's the problem with what I'm doing. (Sorry for my poor English)

Down here there's the code in a snippet!

```js
class Planet
{
    constructor(orbitCenter, color, mass, velocityLimit)
    {
        this.orbitCenter = orbitCenter;
        this.color = color;
        this.mass = mass;
        this.velocityLimit = velocityLimit;

        this.position = createVector(width/2, 50);
        this.radius = 15;
        this.velocity = createVector(30, 10);
        this.acceleration = createVector(0.0, 0.0);
        this.pathPoints = [];
    }

    render() 
    {
        const diameter = this.radius * 2;
        ellipseMode(CENTER);
        noStroke();
        fill(this.color);
        ellipse(this.position.x, this.position.y, diameter);

        if(this.pathPoints.length > 1000) 
        {
            this.pathPoints.splice(0, 1);
        }

        for(let i = 0; i < this.pathPoints.length; i++)
        {
            let pos = this.pathPoints[i];
            fill(255);
            ellipse(pos.x, pos.y, 5, 5);
        }
    }

    update() 
    {     
        this.position.add(this.velocity);
        this.velocity.add(this.acceleration);
        this.acceleration = createVector(this.orbitCenter.x, this.orbitCenter.y)
            .sub(this.position)
            .mult(this.mass);
        this.velocity.limit(this.velocityLimit);
        this.pathPoints.push(this.position);
    }
}

class Star
{
    constructor(color, position, diameter) 
    {
        this.color = color;
        this.position = position;
        this.diameter = diameter;
    }

    render()
    {
        fill(this.color);
        noStroke();
        ellipse(this.position.x, this.position.y, this.diameter);
    }
}

let sun;
let earth, mars;
let sunDiameter = 40;

function setup()
{
    createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
    frameRate(60);

    let sunPos = createVector(width/2, height/2);
    sun = new Star(color(255, 255, 0), sunPos, sunDiameter);

    earth = new Planet(sunPos, color(0, 100, 255), 0.0008, 4.5);
    mars = new Planet(sunPos, color(255, 100, 0), 0.0004, 5);
}

let toggleOrbit = true;
function draw()
{
    background(0);
    sun.render();

    earth.render();
    mars.render();

    if(toggleOrbit)
    {
        earth.update();
        mars.update();
    }
    
}

function windowResized()
{
    resizeCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
    setup();
}

function keyPressed(e)
{
    if(e.key == ' ')
    {
        toggleOrbit = !toggleOrbit;
    }
    
    if(e.key == 'c')
    {
        console.log(earth.getPathPoints());
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Gravity Simulation</title>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.2/p5.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.2/addons/p5.dom.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.2/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>

        <style>
            *
            {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                box-sizing: border-box;
            }

            body
            {
                width: 100vw;
                height: 100vh;
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
                justify-content: center;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If I were you I would start with a simpler example. Can you create a sketch that shows a trail of 3 circles that follow the cursor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write `this.pathPoints.push(this.position)` you end up storing a reference to the object `this.position` rather than its X and Y values, so when it comes the time of drawing the orbit it uses the current value of `this.position` every time. If, instead, you store the X and Y values you'll get the result you want; replace

```
this.pathPoints.push(this.position);
```

for

```
this.pathPoints.push({
    x: this.position.x,
    y: this.position.y
})
```

and you'll see the orbit being drawn.

```js
class Planet
{
    constructor(orbitCenter, color, mass, velocityLimit)
    {
        this.orbitCenter = orbitCenter;
        this.color = color;
        this.mass = mass;
        this.velocityLimit = velocityLimit;

        this.position = createVector(width/2, 50);
        this.radius = 15;
        this.velocity = createVector(30, 10);
        this.acceleration = createVector(0.0, 0.0);
        this.pathPoints = [];
    }

    render() 
    {
        const diameter = this.radius * 2;
        ellipseMode(CENTER);
        noStroke();
        fill(this.color);
        ellipse(this.position.x, this.position.y, diameter);

        if(this.pathPoints.length > 1000) 
        {
            this.pathPoints.splice(0, 1);
        }

        for(let i = 0; i < this.pathPoints.length; i++)
        {
            let pos = this.pathPoints[i];
            fill(255);
            ellipse(pos.x, pos.y, 5, 5);
        }
    }

    update() 
    {     
        this.position.add(this.velocity);
        this.velocity.add(this.acceleration);
        this.acceleration = createVector(this.orbitCenter.x, this.orbitCenter.y)
            .sub(this.position)
            .mult(this.mass);
        this.velocity.limit(this.velocityLimit);
        this.pathPoints.push({
            x: this.position.x,
            y: this.position.y
        })
    }
}

class Star
{
    constructor(color, position, diameter) 
    {
        this.color = color;
        this.position = position;
        this.diameter = diameter;
    }

    render()
    {
        fill(this.color);
        noStroke();
        ellipse(this.position.x, this.position.y, this.diameter);
    }
}

let sun;
let earth, mars;
let sunDiameter = 40;

function setup()
{
    createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
    frameRate(60);

    let sunPos = createVector(width/2, height/2);
    sun = new Star(color(255, 255, 0), sunPos, sunDiameter);

    earth = new Planet(sunPos, color(0, 100, 255), 0.0008, 4.5);
    mars = new Planet(sunPos, color(255, 100, 0), 0.0004, 5);
}

let toggleOrbit = true;
function draw()
{
    background(0);
    sun.render();

    earth.render();
    mars.render();

    if(toggleOrbit)
    {
        earth.update();
        mars.update();
    }
    
}

function windowResized()
{
    resizeCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
    setup();
}

function keyPressed(e)
{
    if(e.key == ' ')
    {
        toggleOrbit = !toggleOrbit;
    }
    
    if(e.key == 'c')
    {
        console.log(earth.getPathPoints());
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Gravity Simulation</title>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.2/p5.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.2/addons/p5.dom.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.2/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>

        <style>
            *
            {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                box-sizing: border-box;
            }

            body
            {
                width: 100vw;
                height: 100vh;
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
                justify-content: center;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```